# How to fix file storage path

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

SO what I am essentially trying to do here is collect information from the user, then collect his/her signature and then attach it to the email.

```
String pilot, ship, to, from, zone1, zone2, CallSign, agent, date, imgPath;
Toolbar toolbar;
Button btn_get_sign, mClear, mGetSign, mCancel, btn_send;
double vesselUnit;
Dialog dialog;
File file;
LinearLayout mContent;
View view;
signature mSignature;
Bitmap bitmap;


File fileDIRECTORY = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)  + "/extSdCard" + "/DigitalSign");
String DIRECTORY= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/extSdCard" + "/DigitalSign";
String rootpic_name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String pic_name = rootpic_name + ".JPEG";
String StoredPath = DIRECTORY + File.separator + rootpic_name + ".JPEG";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_digital_signature);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        pilot = extras.getString("Pilot");
        ship = extras.getString("ship");
        to = extras.getString("to");
        from = extras.getString("from");
        zone1 = extras.getString("zone1");
        zone2 = extras.getString("zone2");
        CallSign = extras.getString("callsign");
        agent = extras.getString("agent");
        vesselUnit = extras.getDouble("vesselunits");
        date = extras.getString("date");
    }
    // Setting ToolBar as ActionBar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Button to open signature panel
    btn_get_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signature);
    btn_send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    // Method to create Directory, if the Directory doesn't exists

    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    // Removing the features of Normal Dialogs
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sig);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    btn_get_sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Function call for Digital Signature
            dialog_action();

        }
    });
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){

            Uri upath = Uri.parse("file://" + StoredPath);
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Pilot: "+pilot+"\nShip: "+ship+"\n"+"Destination: "+to+"\n"+"Departure location: "+from+"\n"+"Zone 1: "+zone1+"\n"+"Zone 2: "+zone2+"\n"+"Callsign: "+CallSign+"\n"+"Angent: "+agent+"\n"+"Vessel Units: "+vesselUnit);
            // set the type to 'email'
            emailIntent.setType("image/*");
            String to[] = {"myemail@gmail.com"};
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            // the attachment
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, upath);
            Log.d("TAG","Tagged");
            // the mail subject
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, pilot+"'s Ticket for "+ship);


            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
        }
    });
}

// Function for Digital Signature
public void dialog_action() {

    mContent = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(getApplicationContext(), null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Dynamically generating Layout through java code
    mContent.addView(mSignature, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    view = mContent;

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v("tag", "Panel Saved");
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            if(isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                file=mSignature.save(view);
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Calling the same class
                recreate();
            }
            else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }
    });
    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("tag", "Panel Cancelled");
            dialog.dismiss();
            // Calling the same class
            recreate();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}


public class signature extends View {
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public File save(View v) {
        Log.v("tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        fileDIRECTORY.mkdirs();
        File nfile = new File (fileDIRECTORY,pic_name);
        try {
            // Output the file
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream  = new FileOutputStream(nfile);
            v.draw(canvas);
            // Convert the output file to Image such as .png
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[] { nfile.toString() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nfile;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string) {
        Log.v("log_tag", string);
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("TRACE","ISWRITEABLE");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("TRACE","ISREADABLE");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
    try{
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG","Not Saved in gallery");
    }

}
```

}

So I have created the directory but the picture is not attaching and not showing up in the file directory. I'm not seeing where my issue arising from but I definitely know hat the picture is either not being processed or not being saved properly in file.

Comment: Do you have that file in your file path a.k.a. `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/DigitalSign/imagename`?

Comment: If you still need help, please provide a [mcve]. In particular, anyone should be able to copy and paste your code and compile it **exactly as you give it**. Personally, I don't mind adding some import statements. However, I cannot begin to guess what method and class contains the code you have given here. Particularly with Android programming, this is important because it shows where in the lifecycle your code executes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok I put up the full code up

Comment: @MehranZamani yes I think so

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to first understand the android storage model.
There is **a lot of confusion** when we talk about internal and external storage in android.
This is mainly because.

> WHAT WE THINK:

Our understanding of external storage is SD CARD which is not quite right.

> WHAT [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) THINKS :

Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.

Here is a good source to read more on
[Internal Storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [External Storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)

**EDIT :** Try not to hard-code path when you are developing an app for multiple manufacturers because it varies from one manufacturer to another.

Answer (score 0):

Change your path directory to

```
File DIRECTORY = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getParent() + "/extSdCard" + "/DigitalSign");
```

Log

> /storage/emulated/extSdCard/DigitalSign

Comment: This still did change the path directory to exactly /storage/emulated/extSdCard/DigitalSign but it still wont attach to the email, so now I don't know where this problem is coming from

Comment: DigitalSign, folder contains the emails right?
Then try changing StoredPath to DIRECTORY 
Uri upath = Uri.parse("file://" + StoredPath);

Comment: Still doesn't attach, I tired doing Uri.parse("file://" + DIRECTORY) and the string with the string version, Uri.parse("file://" + dir)

Comment: when the email comes up for the regular email app I get cannot load image that is 0 bytes and for gmail it says cannot attach empty file so it must either be the way I'm saving it or the filepath. I've spent hours trying to fix this issue but I just cant seem to find whats wrong

Comment: may be you have not the permission to use that file. Have you all done with permissions to get the image?